# Average of multiple averages

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a sql query where I have some averages, now I'd like to have the average of those averages so

```
AVG(q1) as q1,
AVG(q2) as q2,
AVG(q3) as q3,
AVG(q4) as q4,
```

and then I don't know how to get the average of all averages as I can't do `AVG(q1,q2,q3,q4)` and `AVG(q1+q2+q3+q4+q5)` won't return me the total average across all rows and columns, but only the average of each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to compute it manually

```
(AVG(q1) + AVG(q2) ... + AVG(qn))/(n*1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you- I thought of that, but I just thought there might be some way to reuse the values I'd already gotten to not waste processing power - guess there isn't. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Note that the above is mathematically correct only if the number of each of the q's is identical.

Comment: @geoB You say number is identical means what please tell me .. means regular integer or any other

Comment: The original question was for "average of those averages".  This solution is correct.  I think geoB is thinking about the case where there are NULL values for some of the variables but not all; however, that is not relevant to the original question.

Comment: I was actually thinking about the case where one takes the average of 100 items, then the average of 3 items.  The average value of the 113 items is not necessarily the average of two values (one the average of 100 values, one of 3).  However, if all average values have the same number of items, then their average will be the average of the entire set.

Comment: @geoB - it's still reasonable to take the average of averages even if you don't have equal values.  Say you were running a school and wanted to compare teachers' test results.  You could take the average grade of each teacher and then, using the average of averages, compute where the midpoint of the teachers are.  This isn't the same as the average score of every student, but it's a reasonable calculation none-the-less

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can 'reuse' the values with another SELECT

```
SELECT a.*,(q1+q2+q3+q4)/n as avg_all FROM (
  SELECT AVG(q1) as q1,
         AVG(q2) as q2,
         AVG(q3) as q3,
         AVG(q4) as q4.... ) a
```